# sending two ids through a select box

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $doc = new Doc_Schedule();
    $doc->doctor = $_POST['doctor'];
    $doc->department = $_POST['dpt'];
    $doc->sheduledate = $_POST['date'];
    $doc->scheduletime = $_POST['time'];
    if( $doc->create() ) {
        $message = "Doctors Information Saved Successfully";
    } else {
        $message = join("<br/>",$doc->errors);
    }
}
```

---

```
<select name="doctor" id="Deptmentselectbox" class="AllSelectBoxes">
    <option value="">Select Doctor</option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT `fullname`,`depid`,`docid` FROM `doctors` ORDER BY fullname ASC";
    $result = $database->query($sql) or die('cannot connect to the database');
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
       echo"<option value= ".$row['docid'].">".$row['fullname']."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

I have a select box which will show me doctors in a table. when i click a certain doctor i want to send both `doctors.docid` and `doctors.deptid(department id)` to a class for further processing.

I am having trouble finding a solution other dan creating a new select box for department id.

Comment: all solution presented so far should work for you

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0):

combine both values with a delimiter in the options value:

```
echo"<option value= \"{$row['docid']}|{$row['depid']}\">{$row['fullname']}</option>";
```

and separate the values after submit:

```
list($docid,$depid)=explode('|',$_POST['doctor']);
```

alternatively, if you use only `docid`, you'd get `depid` from your database.

And, btw, stop using `mysql_*` because it is deprecated, move to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`!

Answer (score 0):

I would encode the value with some delimiter like this:

```
  echo"<option value= ".$row['docid'].";".$row['deptid'].">".$row['fullname']."</option>";
```

Then you would just call explode within the function:

```
  list($docid, $deptid) = explode($_POST['doctor'], ";");
```

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion would be to use PHP to concatenate and then separate the values.

```
<select name="doctor" id="Deptmentselectbox" class="AllSelectBoxes">
<option value="<?php echo "$doc['doctor']^$doc['department']"; ?> ">Select Doctor</option>
```

Then when processing:

```
$doc = explode("^", $_POST['doctor']);
$doctor = $doc['0'];
$department = $doc['1'];
```

Something like that will send multiple values through one post object.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a comma separated value:

```
echo "<option value=".$doc['docid'].",".$doc['depid']; ?>">".$row['fullname']."</option>"
```

which can be parsed on the server as

```
ID = explode($_POST['doctor'], ",");
```

Or you can use the HTML5 data attribute.

```
echo "<option value=".$doc['docid']." data-DepId=".$doc['depid'].">".$row['fullname']."</option>"
```

Comment: HTML5 data attributes won't work unless you use AJAX to send the data.